# Entity Framework 4: More efficient way to save a hierarchical model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have this Entity that has a lot of related records.  When the web client saves, it sends up a JSON hierarchical model.  The models looks like this:

```
Product[].properties
         .SET1[].properties
         .SET2[].properties
                .SETA[].properties
                .SETA[].SETb[].properties
```

When I go to save this, I have the following flow:

```
Grab DB Product that matches current
Update Properties
Grab and loop through set 1 from DB
    If not found in "to save" set, delete item from set 1
    If found, update it
Grab and loop through set 2 from DB
    If not found in "to save" set, delete item from set 2
    If found, update it
    While we are in Set 2, grab all Set A from DB
        If not found in "to save" set, delete it from set A
        If found, update it
        While we are in Set A, grab all Set b in DB
            If not found in "to save" set, delete it from set b
            If found, update it

Now go back through and insert any in local set not in DB
```

This has to be the worse update algorithm I have seen yet.  Anyone have better code or links that could be a little simpler?  Currently using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is find a way to get all records in a single query. The way you can do this is by using path like fields that represent the hierarchy. An example of this would be:

- Product 1 with code PROD1

  - Property 1 with code PROD1-PROP1
  - Property 2 with code PROD1-PROP2

    - Property 1 of set 1 with code PROD1-SET1-PROP1
    - Property 2 of set 1 with code PROD1-SET1-PROP2

Etc.

Now, you can get all properties by getting all properties starting with the path "PROD1-". Then, after you've retrieved all properties of product 1 in one go, you can do all mutations in memory and store all changes in one batch.